# Knockout 2: How to delay observable object.

Tags: mvvm, observer-pattern, knockout-2.0

Hi i have a problem in knockout 2: I want to do late binding because i am adding data-bind via jQuery

```
$("#button1").on ("click", function() {
        lateBinding = $("#lateBindingElem);
        if (lateBinding.length) {
           lateBinding.attr("data-bind", "text: obs");
        }
     }
});
```

late binding is an html generated on the fly.

I have a view model created already call MyViewModel.

I want to add another attribute or another observable (could be computed or uncomputed) on the fly to existing view model? How would i do this?

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully you have already found an answer elsewhere (7 months ago :D) but since I stumbled upon this question in hopes to find a solution to a similar problem, I might as well and try to give a sort-of-an-answer for anyone else looking into it. This won't let you manipulate the binding for elements you already have bound to a model but allow you to pause binding at given points and bind newly created elements to your current or a different viewmodel.

Built on Ryan Niemeyers **[great article about how to stop bindings](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html)** and accompanying [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fjj7q/) is a **[little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/HHUUf/)** which adds new input elements to dom and binds them to different viewmodels.

Since you can only bind a section of your dom once you need to stop the downward binding at some point using a custom binding..

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
   init: function() {
      return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
   }        
};
```

assign it to a wrapper

```html
<div data-bind="stopBinding: true" id="addNewContentHere"></div>
```

and insert your new elements

```js
function addInput(){
   var data=$('<input type="input" data-bind="value: newInput" />');
   ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel, data[0]);
   $('#addNewContentHere').append(data);
};
```

hope it is of some use :)